# Paypal Button For Google Chrome Extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, paypal, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to add a donate button (because I like money) to my google chrome extension. I'm having trouble with it because the Chrome extension tries to open the paypal created donation button in the popup.html window. When I click the button, my extension just restarts and there is no donation window.

I have tried using chrome.tab.create() to try to make it open to a tab but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

The code to the donation button is as follows:

```
<form action="chrome.tabs.create ({'url': 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'});" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXX">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

Any help with this would be great!

Thanks

Comment: disclaimer: I like money too. Actually I'm also developing an extension and was extremely curious if you find the donate button effective. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use a [service like this](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/lacostenycoder) if you want something with a little more pizzazz for example https://www.buymeacoffee.com/lacostenycoder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a link instead of a form: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=xxxxxxx

Comment: an elegant and simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: What if I need to send custom data, to verify the purchase?  A form sends the needed POST variables, a link doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
<form action="chrome.tabs.create ({'url': 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'});" method="post">
```

Try:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_blank" method="post">
```

Comment: the same thing happens, the extension just restarts. Thanks for the suggestion anyhow!

Comment: Well, this actually works. Tried in Chromium 18.0.1025.168 . Maybe @infinityLoop didn't reload the extension? Maybe old versions of Chrome can't handle the target?

Answer (score 0):

To add on to PayPal_Robert:
If you still want the PayPal donate image linked in there, try:

```
<a target='_blank' href='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=xxxxxxxx'>
  <image src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0">
</a>
```

Just change the hosted_button_id parameter to your own.

Answer (score 0):

Like in usual front-end programming, use **preventDefault()** function at **addEventlistener**

```
const submit = document.querySelector("#submit");

submit.addEventListener("click", submit_click, false);

function submit_click(event)
{
  // whatever action

  event.preventDefault();
}
```