# form post in Chrome extension popup not doing anything

Tags: google-chrome, popup, google-chrome-extension, forms, http-post

I am making a chrome extension and I have a popup.html page that contains a form with method post, it does not do anything when opened using the popup button however if the page is opened  as an options page or just a normal html page, the form posts fine and the new page is loaded.

so something in the popup is preventing the form from working.

I cannot figure out why, anyone know how to fix/work around this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do an AJAX POST request. A quick Google search brought up [this post](http://markashleybell.com/building-a-simple-google-chrome-extension.html).

Comment: how would I use this for a paypal donation button ? it needs to open a  new tab with the donation page after it is clicked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438292/paypal-button-for-google-chrome-extension

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks. Sorry for asking even though it was already here, I didn't think to associate the problem with a paypal button until after I had already posted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an answer duplicate of [Paypal Button For Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438292/paypal-button-for-google-chrome-extension).

Just in case that somebody arrives here, try adding a simple target="_blank" to your  tag (Works with Paypal donate buttons, for example)