# Paypal donate button not working in chrome://extensions/ (OptionsV2)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, paypal, google-chrome-extension

I made a Chrome extension and I made an donate button if someone want to make donation.

But the PayPal button only works when you click it in optons of the extension itself (`chrome-extension://myidhere/gitmb/options/options.html`) but it does not work [embedded in the extensions folder](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2) (`chrome://extensions/?options=myidhere`)

Why is that? Is something wrong in the code? Or is chrome blocking it?

Button code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----[snip]-----END PKCS7-----">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: I edited your question to remove the extension link (can be seen as spammy), added a link to the Options docs and included the relevant code.

Comment: On topic, embedded options pages probably can't submit forms.

Comment: See if [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7447737/452587) works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This probably fails because the embedded page cannot navigate to the post URL. Try changing the `target` to `"_blank"` in the form.

If that doesn't work, you may need to [do the POST yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387217/chrome-extension-development-post-to-new-tab).

Comment: Thank You for edit. I tried to change the target to "_blank" and it is not working. I will look to the POST option you posted. Thank You for your time. I will let You know if I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of late answer:

**Button as link**

I've managed the same thing through implementation of the link with target blank attribute instead of the form. Paypal offers this option.

I realized too, that my extension's popup containing the paypal button's form opens WAYS slower, as with the link.

**Button as form**

Beside of this (haven't tested it by myself), it should work, if the form element is used with target blank attribute.